# Using sed to add text to a file before and after word

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a file with words, one word per line, which I now want to change so that is becomes a .sh-file with an egrep-search string for each word. The search string I want in the end looks like this:

```bash
`egrep -wi '\|WORD\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > WORD_frekvens.txt`
```

My word file looks like this:

```bash
$ more -10 word_file.txt
anakonda
ord
tröja
bord
glas
pension
larm
risk
försening
rapport
```

I have tried to do this with the following string:

```bash
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/egrep -wi '\''\\|\1\\.\\.nn'\'' stats_all.txt > \1_frekvens.txt/' word_file.txt | more
```

But it gives the output:

```
_frekvens.txt_all.txt > WORD
```

Why doesn't it work to use the `\1` here? It seems to be this part that's the problem, as it works if I exchange it for a word.

Anything I write after `\1` ends up writing over the content of `\1`, i.e. "WORD". If I write something only before `\1` it works fine.

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: I think @Ron's edit has corrected the error, hasn't it? the original had un-escaped parentheses around the capture group i.e. `(.*)` in place of `\(.*\)`: the former requires `-r` or `-E` mode (basic sed treats parentheses as literal).

Comment: Thanks. But no, I'm afraid not. I have done the search with `\(.*\)` all along (don't know why it ended up un-escaped in my question...). Still seems to be a problem.

Comment: What's your shell?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu via VirtualBox (if this is a shell).

Comment: Add the output of `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Please make a test: Install another shell, eg zsh: `sudo apt-get install zsh`. Open a terminal and start the shell `zsh`. Start your script again.

Comment: And give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't work either. I used zsh, but all the scripts (sed, perl and awk) gave the same result as earlier for me. @A.B.

Comment: Can you test is on another machine?

Comment: Yes, good idea. And now I noticed I hadn't actually got the zsh working. Thought you just wrote `zsh` after installing, but it still seems to be bash running when I check. Anyhow, I'll try on another machine and hopefully it'll work! Thanks for all the help! @A.B.

Comment: Only an idea: `LANG=C sed -e 's/\(.*\)/egrep -wi '\''\\|\1\\.\\.nn'\'' stats_all.txt > \1_frekvens.txt/' word_file.txt`

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry... Gave some additional info in the question if this might be a clue to the problem. But as I said I will try another machine soon and I think that should work. @A.B.

Comment: Ok, Windows line breaks. :) I have updated my answer, Thx @SylvainPineau

Comment: But than this is your output `_frekvens.txt_all.txt > WORD` AND `egrep -wi '\|\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > _frekvens.txt` and not only `_frekvens.txt_all.txt > WORD` as you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also process your list of words with the following `perl` command:

```
$ perl -ne 's/\s*$//; print "egrep -wi \047\|${_}\.\.nn\047 stats_all.txt > ${_}_frekvens.txt\n"' word_file.txt
```

Note that I'm using `\047` to avoid escaping `'` (single quote).

With a dummy `word_file.txt`:

```
foo
bar
```

The output is:

```
egrep -wi '\|foo\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > foo_frekvens.txt
egrep -wi '\|bar\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > bar_frekvens.txt
```

Comment: You need a `\ ` before the `.` : `\`egrep -wi '\|WORD\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > WORD_frekvens.txt\``

Comment: I have changed your example output, I hope it's ok. And a +1 =)

Comment: Thanks. I get this output though: `_frekvens.txtll.txt > WORD`. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Something to do with the Ubuntu/Perl version?? I understand one can have different settings for RegExs? Maybe this has something to do with it? (As you can tell, I am not very used to working in the terminal.)

Comment: @Ingrid I know why you got this weird ouput. Your input file contains Windows line breaks (`\r\n`). Please try my updated command.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! Yes, that was the answer! Had no idea the line breaks were different in Windows. But great! Thanks all you guys! All of the solutions would work great if I'd only made the word file in Linux... @A.P.

Comment: @SylvainPineau only wow!

Answer (score 1):

*As it has turned out, you use Windows line breaks (`\r\n`) in the file. Due to this fact, I have adjusted my commands, note the `… gsub(/\r/,"") …`*

This is a simple task for `awk`:

```
awk 'gsub(/\r/,"") {print "`egrep -wi \047\\|" $_ "\\.\\.nn\047 stats_all.txt > "$_"_frekvens.txt`"}' <your_input_file>
```

to write the output in the *input* file:

```
awk -i inplace 'gsub(/\r/,"") {print "`egrep -wi \047\\|" $_ "\\.\\.nn\047 stats_all.txt > "$_"_frekvens.txt`"}' <your_input_file>
```

to write the output in a new file:

```
awk 'gsub(/\r/,"") {print "`egrep -wi \047\\|" $_ "\\.\\.nn\047 stats_all.txt > "$_"_frekvens.txt`"}' <your_input_file> > output_file
```

---

Sample with inline editing

```
% cat words
foo
bar

% awk -i inplace 'gsub(/\r/,"") {print "`egrep -wi \047\\|" $_ "\\.\\.nn\047 stats_all.txt > "$_"_frekvens.txt`"}' words

% cat words                                                                                               
`egrep -wi '\|foo\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > foo_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|bar\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > bar_frekvens.txt`
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but for some reason this doesn't work either. I get the same kind of problem as earlier somehow. The output is: `_frekvens.txt_all.txt > WORD`. I must be doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is...

Comment: @Ingrid Which output? =)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite used to this, so I sent it off too early.. :)

Comment: What is the content of your input file?

Comment: @Ingrid What is the content of your input file?

Comment: It's just a list of words, i.e. a word on each line, just like you wrote in your example.

Comment: @Ingrid You have the same problem with the perl script in the other answer?

Comment: @Ingrid Which of the commands you've used?

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem with the perl script. I used the first of the awk-commands.

Comment: Please, post a part of your input file in the question.

Comment: Thanks! I actually haven't had an opportunity to try this on the file I had earlier with Windows line breaks, but I made a new word_file.txt in Linux and the earlier answer of course worked fine then! I'll try the new solution when I get to Windows again. (Haven't got enough reputation to up any answer yet I'm afraid, but sure will later!)

Answer (score 1):

The following command:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\`egrep -wi '\\\|\1\\\\.\\\.nn' stats_all.txt > \1_frekvens.txt\`/" word_file.txt
```

gives the output:

```
`egrep -wi '\|anakonda\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > anakonda_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|ord\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > ord_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|tröja\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > tröja_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|bord\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > bord_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|glas\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > glas_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|pension\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > pension_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|larm\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > larm_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|risk\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > risk_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|försening\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > försening_frekvens.txt`
`egrep -wi '\|rapport\.\.nn' stats_all.txt > rapport_frekvens.txt`
```